# Create Dict from multiple Lists with duplicate Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have four lists named `designName`,`creatorName`,`fabric_names` and `data` the `data` list consist of multiple duplicate values which I want to map it to it's asscociated design name and creator name like:

```
Catching Fireflies thestorysmith FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON 1.75 10.58 18.22
Catching Fireflies thestorysmith FABRIC_SATIN 1.75 11.85 19.71
Catching Fireflies thestorysmith FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA 1.75 11.85 19.71....

Spoonflower Color Map spoonflower_help FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON N/A N/A 16.4
Spoonflower Color Map spoonflower_help FABRIC_SATIN N/A N/A 17.74
Spoonflower Color Map spoonflower_help FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA N/A N/A 17.74...

Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue at_the_cottage FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON 1.75 10.58 18.22
Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue at_the_cottage FABRIC_SATIN 1.75 11.85 19.71
Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue at_the_cottage FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA 1.75 11.85 19.71
```

### Data:

```
desigName = ['Catching Fireflies', 'Spoonflower Color Map', 'Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue']
creatorName = ['thestorysmith', 'spoonflower_help', 'at_the_cottage']
fabric_names = ['FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'FABRIC_SATIN', 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA']
data = [('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22),('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22),('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22),... ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),... ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71),...]
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to turn this data into one ordered dict like the following.

```
{('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name_00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_00': 10.58, 'meter_00': 18.22, 'fabric_name_01': 'FABRIC_SATIN', 'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_01': 11.85, 'meter_01': 19.71, 'fabric_name_02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_02': 11.85, 'meter_02': 19.71}}
```

I tried:

```
for fab in fabric_names:
        print(fab)
    for name, creator in zip(designName, creatorName):
        for fab_type in fabric_names:
            Design_Name = name
            Creator_Name = creator
            test_swatch_meter = data[1]
            fat_quarter_meter = data[2]
            meter = data[3]

            if (name, creator) not in items_dict.keys():
                items_dict[(name, creator)] = {}
            itemCount = len(items_dict[(name, creator)].values()) / 4
            items_dict[(name, creator)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fab_type,
            'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
            'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
            'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(items_dict, orient='index').reset_index(drop=False)
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0':'designName','level_1':'screenName'})
df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

but cannot get it to format like above.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 I updated the question with Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Dumping all your code into your question is hardly providing a MRE, please reduce the MRE to the essential part of your code dealing with your specific problem.   Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @itprorh66 I updated the code with all the requirements I guess.

Comment: @itprorh66 Thank you so much for the guide to make this question presentable.

Comment: Since py 3.7 dictionaries have been ordered. Can you show the desired structure in terms of plain dicts?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure here is the plain dict structure: `{('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name_00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_00': 10.58, 'meter_00': 18.22, 'fabric_name_01': 'FABRIC_SATIN', 'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_01': 11.85, 'meter_01': 19.71, 'fabric_name_02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_02': 11.85, 'meter_02': 19.71}}`

Comment: Why don't you just `zip()` them all?

Comment: @accdias I tried `zip()` them all just giving me the names and creator with some values from data not all data and it's not associated with valid values that is why I decided to go for `key:value` structure so later if I want to export it to csv or any other file format I can do it easily

Comment: Are you sure? I'm confident that `list(zip(desigName, creatorName, data))` yields exactly what you want.

Comment: You really don't need a `dict()` with sequentially enumerated keys because that is just what a `list()` is for.

Comment: This looks a lot like an xy problem. I'm suspicious of your data structure's usefulness

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you decided you needed an OrderedDict structure for this problem, I have iomplemented the solution using a standard dictionary making use of the fact that since the advent of Python 3, a standard dictionary returns the keys in the order that they were inserted.
While it is quite possible to do this using a series of complex zip caLLs, and I am sure someone will provide such a solution, I choose to implement the solution using a function which simply walks through the data structure and creates first the keys for the top-level dictionary and then the key value pairs for the inner-dictionaries and combines them.  Here is my solution:

```
def combine_info(dn, cn, fn, dt):
    work_dict = {}
    freq = len(fn)
    for indx, val in enumerate(dn):
        ky = (val, cn[indx])
        inner_dict = {}
        for ptr, inkey in enumerate(fn):
            kp = 0
            while kp+ptr < freq:
                inner_dict[f'fabric_name_{kp:02}'] = data[kp+ptr][0]
                inner_dict[f'test_swatch_meter_{kp:02}'] = data[kp+ptr][1]
                inner_dict[f'fat_quarter_meter_{kp:02}'] = data[kp+ptr][2]
                inner_dict[f'meter_{kp:02}'] = data[kp+ptr][3]
                kp += 1
            work_dict[ky] =   inner_dict
    return work_dict
```

Running `combine_info(desigName, creatorName, fabric_names, data)` Yields the following:

```
{('Catching Fireflies',
  'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name_00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_00': 10.58, 'meter_00': 18.22, 'fabric_name_01': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_01': 10.58, 'meter_01': 18.22, 'fabric_name_02': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_02': 10.58, 'meter_02': 18.22},
 ('Spoonflower Color Map',
  'spoonflower_help'): {'fabric_name_00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_00': 10.58, 'meter_00': 18.22, 'fabric_name_01': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_01': 10.58, 'meter_01': 18.22, 'fabric_name_02': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_02': 10.58, 'meter_02': 18.22},
 ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue',
  'at_the_cottage'): {'fabric_name_00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_00': 10.58, 'meter_00': 18.22, 'fabric_name_01': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_01': 10.58, 'meter_01': 18.22, 'fabric_name_02': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 'fat_quarter_meter_02': 10.58, 'meter_02': 18.22}}
```

Comment: "since the advent of Python 3, a standard dictionary returns the keys in the order that they were inserted" This statement is incorrect. `dict`s because insertion-ordered as an implementation detail of the CPython reference interpreter (which copied an earlier implementation detail of PyPy) as of CPython 3.6, and because insertion-ordered as a language guarantee as of 3.7. They were not insertion ordered before that time.